# Why is there a switch from Sin to Samech?

Tags: writing-printing, maseches-kesubos, spelling-variants

related [Relationship between Samekh and Sin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/relationship-between-samekh-and-sin)

(referencing the Schottenstein edition of Masechet Ketubot -- I haven't checked other printings)

In the mishna on 46b, the text reads נשאת יתר עליו הבעל -- As for a married woman, the husband has more entitlements than the father. The word for the married woman is נשאת .

But in the gemara on 47a, the text I have reads ניסת יתר עליו הבעל (text confirmed on Sefaria and on e-daf).

I know that the two letters are often interchanged (discussion in the related question and a mention [here](http://www.balashon.com/2006/11/)) but I don't know WHY, within one particular text, there would be a switch. Does it change meaning, or indicate anything about the textual composition? Are there versions of the gemara that don't have this change?

Comment: perhaps with a sin is hebrew and samach is aramiac?

Comment: But the gemara is quoting the mishna.