# Why does "שוכו" change into "סוכו?"

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

In [Tracte Megilah 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.4?lang=he) - it lists the children of בתיה - the daughter of פרעה.

One of the children's names is חבר - father of שוכו.

The Gemara then explains that all of these names of the kids - are all really משה רבינו!

The Gemara then explains why משה was called these names.

When explaining why he was called שוכו - it says "סוכו" with a "ס" - not at "ש"!

Why does the spelling of the name change?

Comment: Sin and samech switch often in midrash and in poetry, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4286/759

Comment: @double AA but what's the point in switching

Comment: Wasn’t the point because the connection to moshe was with using the word סכה with a samech, so they changed the sin to make the connection more clear

Comment: @CuriousYid thank you!